# Javascript Price Calculator Doesn't Work when Fields are Auto Populated by URL Params on Page Load

Tags: javascript

I have a price calculator working when a dropdown field is changed but when the dropdown is automatically selected via URL parameters, the calculator doesn't update.

I've tried a number of methods but I'll just show you the working code for on change events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcTotal() {
var monthlyBB = document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,'');
var installBB = document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,'');

}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("selected_package").onchange = function() { 
    var v=this.value; 

    if('Select Package' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;0";
                    document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;0";
        calcTotal();

    } else if('product1' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;28";
        calcTotal();

    } else if('product2' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;35";
        calcTotal();

    }    else if('product3' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;45";
        calcTotal();

    }     else if('product4' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;20";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;65";
        calcTotal();

    }   
}
```

An alternative form of the script was created by Osama in the comments

```
document.getElementById("selected_package").onchange = function () {
var installPackagePrice, monthlyPackagePrice;

switch (this.value) {
  case "Select Package":
    installPackagePrice = 0;
    monthlyPackagePrice = 0;
    break;
  case "product1":
    installPackagePrice = 40;
    monthlyPackagePrice = 28;
    break;
  case "product2":
    installPackagePrice = 40;
    monthlyPackagePrice = 35;
    break;
  case "product3":
    installPackagePrice = 40;
    monthlyPackagePrice = 45;
    break;
  case "product4":
    installPackagePrice = 20;
    monthlyPackagePrice = 65;
    break;
}

document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;" + installPackagePrice;
document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;" + monthlyPackagePrice;

/*calcTotal();*/
```

}

Comment: can you post your full code please ?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated it

Comment: try calling the function at the end of the `if else` statement. Not in each condition.

Comment: You've missed the part with _"when the dropdown is automatically selected via URL parameters"_. But most likely you have to trigger the `change`  event yourself or use a named function for the event handler and call it after changing the dropdown

Comment: Offtopic: A slightly more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) version of your change handler: http://jsbin.com/tiwocebanu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: which part of the functin dea with url parameters?

Comment: The dropdown is selected via url params handled by contact form 7 and is working correctly Osama

Thank you Andreas that looks way better

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jquery? Jquery Library usually covers all change event with the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected_package').change(function(){
       var v=$(this).val(); 

    if('Select Package' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;0";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;0";
        calcTotal();

    } else if('product1' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;28";
        calcTotal();

    } else if('product2' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;35";
        calcTotal();

    }    else if('product3' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;40";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;45";
        calcTotal();

    }     else if('product4' === v) {
        document.getElementById("install_package").innerHTML = "&pound;20";
        document.getElementById("monthly_package").innerHTML = "&pound;65";
        calcTotal();

    }  
    });
});
```

Also you could trigger the change event whenever automatic change occurs.

```
$('#selected_package').trigger('change');
```